# Is there a way to check if a youtube video is claimed using its API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to build a listing of YouTube videos using php API and have to display next to video whether it is claimed by someone or not?

What should my approach be to this.?

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me... try to "define" claimed.

Comment: Have you checked the official API? Have you even tried googling? If it's not in official API it can't be checked.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry  Goikiu for the confusion i might have caused, I wanted to check if video has some copyrights with it , whether the video is marked as claimed by someone.

hello Dovydas, I also tried checking in the API parameters but unfortunately i  might have missed it or my ways of finding it might have been wrong.

So just wanted to confirm are there any ways to find such information.

Comment: Found, this link can help you: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos , you'll find this line contentDetails.licensedContent

Comment: Thanks Goiku, This is very usefull. I will explore on it further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
contentDetails.licensedContent  boolean
```

Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means that the content has been claimed by a YouTube content partner.

Source: [Google Developer Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)