# Search official videos only with youtube api v3

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've come across many articles (no. 14 on [this](http://www.mstoic.com/15-youtube-search-operator-improve-youtube-search/), and no. 3 on [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-search/19261/), for example) advising the addition of

**, partner**

at the end of a query to return only official videos, i.e. videos from partner channels. However, such a query does not seem to work on YouTube. It just treats "partner" as a part of the query and returns results according to that. Nor are there any parameters listed on the v3 [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). Any workarounds?

My query looks like

```
query = 'Whatever'
params = {
        "q": query,
        "part": "id,snippet",
        "type":"video"
    }     
 videos = youtube_api.search().list(**params).execute()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a youtube video is claimed using its API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014696/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-youtube-video-is-claimed-using-its-api)

Comment: @Destrif Thanks for the suggestion. However, on adding "contentDetails" to my "part" parameter, I get an HttpError 400, so I am sticking just to "id" and "snippet". Which means the contentDetails.licensedContent is inaccessible.

Comment: @Destrif, found a solution to that here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393842/contentdetails-or-duration-not-coming-using-youtube-v3-api), but it would be very expensive. Can't afford so many hits to the api.

Comment: Show me how you construct your request. To access : contentDetails.licensedContent

Comment: I followed the solution as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393842/contentdetails-or-duration-not-coming-using-youtube-v3-api). It's getting the job done but has a computation overhead.

Comment: I done some tests with `, partner` and seems that  only prioritizes the content from partners. At least on website.